# How to speed up IntelliJ on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm using Mac OSX 10.9 and Intellij Idea 13 on a decked out machine (7i processor, 16GB RAM, 64 bit, etc.).  I have things working well; however, it seems to me that Intellij is running pretty slow (approx. 5 mins to boot up, almost a full 2 minutes to compile a system out print line class, etc.).  As a frame of reference I have looked through numerous posts and have landed on the configurations below.  My question is this.  Does anyone else use a similar set up and have it running quicker?  If so, what modifications have you made to your environment to speed things up.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Java Version:

Switched from jdk1.6 to jdk1.7

idea.vmoptions:

```
-ea
-server
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
-Xss16m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
-XX:+UseSplitVerifier
-XX:CompileThreshold=10000
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
-XX:+UseStringCache
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
```

info.plist (modification):

```
<key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
<array>
  <string>x86_64</string>
</array>

  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.7*</string>
```

Comment: Have you tried using another IDE? Were the results the same? Five minutes startup is ridiculous, even for a Mac. Do you have an SSD?

Comment: Which key system of your PC is slowing you down? Is the CPU or Harddrive?

Comment: Given you have good RAM, try with -Xms6g -Xmx6g.

Comment: Some of your arguments are not useful - such as -XX:+PrintGCDetails, UseSplitVerifier.   I would start with vanilla vmoptions file and increase only memory and MaxPermSize.

Comment: I have used xcode and eclipse; both with better results.  I'm trying to get intellij to work so I can work on a common environment with some friends I develop with.  The CPU, RAM and Hard Drive are all working fine (I'm running diagnostics on them during boot-up) so I'm assuming this is an intellij configuration issue.  I'm going to try Jayan's suggestions now.

Comment: Okay, so I have the following vmoptions and from what I can tell, this is the min I can run with.  There isn't a noticeable difference one way or the other.  -Xms6g
-Xmx6g
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

Comment: Please check the plugins, maybe you've enabled more than you actually need

Comment: Would those impact the start-up of Intellij or the *Run execution at compile time?  It seems to me that they may impact the start-up but if they aren't included in any classes they wouldn't impact the run time.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you *not* to use all these VM options (especially those controlling garbage collector) unless you actually measure they will improve performance.
Please report reproducable performance problems as described here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Which ones would you suggest using?  The slow performance has returned so I'm starting to experiment with this again.  I've talked to a few people who had similar setups and it seems that they tended to have the same issue and are using their pc's now.  I would really like to get this working on my mac.  Here is what I'm using now:

Comment: -server
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
-Xss16m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-agentlib:yjpagent=delay=10000

Comment: As I wrote above, I'd suggest _not_ to set any special VM options except for suitable -Xmx and required -XX:MaxPermSize & -Xss.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because doing that doesn't work.  I was hoping you had a specific example as to what would work on this set up.  I appreciate the help; however, I'm starting to think this configuration may have nothing to do with the slow start up rather another dependency embedded within intellij.  I will figure it out and post my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the scoop.  There is a lot of stuff out there about changing the heap size, garbage collectors and what not.  It may not be the root cause of your problem.  Be sure to understand what you are setting in your vmoptions file as several suggestions aren't really supported any longer.  I worked with the folks at IntelliJ going back and forth with log files and what not and it boils down to this.  Check your anti virus.  After adjusting my anti-virus, the following settings have IntelliJ screaming.  Please note that this was the cause to my individual problem; so be sure to check your log files because that is where I started to find answers.

JDK 1.6

.vmoptions is running in the /Application/IntelliJ13/bin:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

*notice that you don't need to allocate huge amounts of system resources.  If you set up your system correctly it isn't needed.

Idea.plist:

```
<key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
<array>
  <string>x86_64</string>
  <string>i386</string>
</array>

<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*</string>
```

I know it is simple but it works.